# PHP MySQL UPDATE query not posting value from text box

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a form with a select list populated from a database. When the query is executed, a success message is returned however the database is not updated.

Here is the form:

```
 <form id="formPrice">
 <?php
 $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'something', 'something', 'something') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');
$result = $conn->query("SELECT PlotNumber FROM Developments WHERE Development = 'GREENGRAVES' AND Price = 'BOOKED'");
echo "<select name='plot_update'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<option value=\"Plot\">" . $row['PlotNumber'] . "
</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input name="price" type="text" id="price">
<input name="update" type="submit" class="update_price">
</form>
```

Here is the ajax request:

```
 $('.update_price').click(function() {
 var FormData = $('form').serialize(); 
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../php/update_price.php',
    data : FormData,
    success:function(html){
        document.getElementById("result_two").innerHTML=html;   
    }  
 });
 return false;
 });
```

Here is the php

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$price = $_POST['price'];
$plot = $_POST['plot'];
$sql = "UPDATE Developments SET Price = '".$price."' WHERE PlotNumber = '".$plot."' ";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

The page displays "record updated successfully" in the result div, however database entry remains unchanged. Any ideas why? I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you checked through your browser console that all data properly going to server side & you are getting the $_POST value in your PHP script?

Comment: `document.getElementById("result_two")` where's that id in the html or is that irrelevant? and your POST array for `plot` doesn't match the form element's name; error reporting would have told you about it; undefined index.

Comment: result_two is in a div underneath where the success/error message is displayed. In which way does the form not match? The 'price' element should be from the 'price' input, and plot from the select?

Comment: ^ just like I said. It doesn't match. I just didn't write it all out.

Comment: Have changed post to plot_update and still not working

Comment: I am aware that a true return does not mean that it has updated, I am just not sure WHY in this case after updating the POST

Comment: No errors coming from error logs or browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seemed to be with this line in the front end form:

```
echo "<option value=\"Plot\">" . $row['PlotNumber'] . "</option>";
```

When I changed to:

```
echo "<option>" . $row['PlotNumber'] . "</option>";
```

it worked!

Answer (score 0):

There is issues with form field under php script:

change your php script to the following:

```
<form id="formPrice">
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'something', 'something', 'something')
or die ('Cannot connect to db');
$result = $conn->query("SELECT PlotNumber FROM Developments WHERE Development = 'GREENGRAVES' AND Price = 'BOOKED'");
echo "<select name='plot'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=" . $row['PlotNumber'] . ">" . $row['PlotNumber'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input name="price" type="text" id="price">
<input name="update" type="button" class="update_price">
```

Always make sure - Select option value needs to have the actual value of the record and select field will have the form field name.